# Convert apache rule to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

If I have this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(_js|_css)\/(.+)\.\w+\.(min.js|min.css)$ $1/$2.$3 [L,NC]
```

what would the corresponding rule in Nginx be?

I thought it would be

```
location ~* ^/(_js|_css)\/(.+)\.\w+\.(min.js|min.css)$ {
  try_files $uri /$1/$2.$3;
}
```

but I get a 404 on js/css files with that. The same files don't 404 if using Apache with the rule above instead of Nginx.

Comment: This location block cannot generate 404, so either the rewritten URI is hitting another location that generates the 404, or this location is not processing the original request in the first place. Look at all of the `location` blocks in the `server` block and check you access and error logs. If you want `/$1/$2.$3` to be handled within this location, you need to change it to `try_files $uri /$1/$2.$3 =404;` so it's not the final term.

Comment: @Tyssen Your nginx rule is correct, but it (as well as an apache rule) deals only with `*.min.js` and `*.min.css` files. If you get an HTTP 404 for some other JS/CSS files, search your apache configuration for additional rules.